# Why does Java allow code blocks for enum constants?

Tags: java, enums

I was typing an enum of Pokemon types when suddenly

```
public enum Type {

    NORMAL () { // This is the question. Why does Java allow this?
        int x = 10; // Only accepts variables?
    };

    Type () {}

}
```

This code compiled correctly.

What's the use of a code block for constants?

Comment: Have a look at the "planet"-example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html to see what it can be useful for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Code blocks in enums allows you to override methods defined in the enum type. For instance

```
enum Foo {
    PEAR,
    BANANA() {
        @Override
        public void doFoo() {
            System.out.println("Banana foo");
        }
    },
    APPLE,
    GRAPE;

    public void doFoo() {
        System.out.println("Default foo");
    }
}
```

Here `Foo.BANANA.doFoo()` would produce `"Banana foo"`, while calling `doFoo()` on any other `Foo` would produce `"Default foo"`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, enums are not simple aliases for integers, like in many other programming languages. In Java, enum values are full-blown objects which can have user-defined data, methods, etc.

If you write an enum class as follows:

```
enum PetType { CAT, GOLDFISH }
```

what actually happens is that you define a class `PetType` (which is a subclass of the standard Java class `Enum`) and two instances of this class, `CAT` and `GOLDFISH`. The Java compiler makes sure that there never will be more `PetType` instances, and that `CAT` and `GOLDFISH` always refer to the same object.

But other than that `MyEnum` is a normal class. You can define member variables and methods for it, which you can initialize through a constructor:

```
enum PetType {
    CAT(true),
    GOLDFISH(false);

    private boolean isHairy;

    PetType(boolean isHairy) {
        this.isHairy = isHairy;
    }

    public boolean isHairy() {
        return isHairy;
    }
}
```

This you can use in your own code:

```
public static void displayWhetherHairy(CatType catType) {
    if (catType.isHairy()) {
        System.out.println("This pet is hairy!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("This pet is not hairy!");
    }
}
```

This is why you can use code in an enum definition.

What you do in your code is basically define another (anonymous) subclass of the `Type` class, which defines an additional member variable `x` with value 10. The only instance of this subclass is the `NORMAL` object. If you compile your code, you will see a file of the form `Type$1.class`, which is this subclass.